# how do i fill my array with doubles from a file that is separated by a commas

Tags: c, arrays, double, fopen, argv

so i need to open a text that will look something like this:

```
45.687794,-785.645682
13.168486,-946.132461
94.138467,-456.48796
65.111158,-179.648315
```

and place them into an array so my current code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    double Array[8];
```

how would i get each number into the array while going through the file and skipping the comma? 
i believe i need to at some point use atof to turn it from a char to a double and i have tried to use a do-while loop.

I expected the do-while loop would fill the array with the numbers and i thought using "%f," would turn it into a double, ignore the comma and place it into the array but instead it did nothing.
Edit: so my "%f," should be "%1f," instead should the comma inside remain?

```
i = 0;
    do
    {
       fscanf(fp, "%f,", &Array[i]);
        i++;
    }
while (i < 8);
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `double` is `%lf`.

Comment: Avoid posting "but it didn't work.".  It attracts down-votes.  Instead, be descriptive, what was seen, what was expected?

Comment: Compiler should have warned about `double Array[8]; ... fscanf(fp, "%f,", &Array[i]);`   Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: ok, well i expected the do-while loop would fill the array with the numbers and i thought using "%f," would turn it into a double, ignore the comma and place it into the array

Comment: Your main problem is the conversion specification error.  You should check the return from `fscanf()` but you’ll never know when the comma fails to match, but you aren’t particularly worried about that. If you want to ensure you’ve got two comma-separated numbers per line, read the lines with `fgets()` and parse the result with `sscanf()`.  This is often a good technique. It also makes for better error reporting.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: use a for loop, check your return codes, and enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usage `%f` in `fscanf(fp, "%f,", &Array[i]);` instead of `%lf`.

`printf()` and `scanf()` are both variadic functions.

`%f` and `%lf` may be used interchangeably in the case of `printf()` but not `scanf()`.

`float` arguments of `printf()` will automatically get converted to `double` anyway due to default type promotion of the function arguments.
See [here](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314060/c-type-conversion-when-passing-an-argument-on-a-function-call).

But in the case of `scanf()`, the arguments are all addresses and hence there is no similar promotion. Hence a `%lf` will make `scanf()` use `sizeof(double)` bytes and a `%f` would consider `sizeof(float)`.

See a demo [here](https://ideone.com/xJ13c0).

Comment: Im still confused how i would use this? when i change the "%f" nothing changes and my array wasn't filled

Comment: @KunaiBunsen See the demo I added. In it the standard input is assumed to be the file. Change it to the file pointer when you use it.