# What is this second sentence exactly saying?

Tags: c, char, int, function-prototypes

> Since an argument of a function call is an expression, type conversions also take place when arguments are passed to function. In absence of a function prototype, char and short become int, and float becomes double.

I got the first sentence. Can someone please explain the second sentence?

> In absence of a function prototype, char and short become int, and float becomes double.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Must declare function prototype in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c)

Comment: @bereal No, it doesn't.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314094/10281456 Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Abhay Aravinda It does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard C provides two ways of declaring functions. The modern way, called a prototype, declares the types of the parameters. For example, `void foo(char a, float b);`. The old way does not include the parameter types. For example, `void foo();`.

In the old method of declaring functions, integer arguments narrower than `int` are passed as `int` (or, in certain cases, as `unsigned int`), and `float` arguments are passed as `double`. This arose largely because of the circumstances in which C developed and the flexibility with which it handled small integers.

If you call a function declared with a prototype, the C implementation knows the types of the parameters and converts each argument to the destination type. If you call a function declared without a prototype, the C implementation does not know the true types of the parameters in the function definition, but it knows that narrow integer types must be passed as `int` (or `unsigned int`) and `float` arguments must be passed as `double`. So any arguments of these types are converted to `int`, `unsigned int`, or `double`, as appropriate.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You ameliorated my perspicaciousness.